# the sum of the first five natural numbers

Tags: c++

I wanna get the sum of the first five natural numbers, but there in this this code something is wrong, need to find the misstake ? Help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 1, thesum;

    while(i <= 5)
    {
        thesum += i;
        i++;
    }

    cout << thesum;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? Is the output different? It won't compile? It crashes? Missed a closing brace due to the wacky indentation?

Comment: Initialize `thesum=0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't initialized `thesum` variable. Initialize it to `0`.

```
int i = 1, thesum = 0;
```

Otherwise it will invoke **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 2):

As it was already pointed out you did not initialize local variable thesum. So it has some arbitrary value.
Also there is no any need to include header `<cstdlib>` because no one declaration from it is used.
As variable i is not used outside the loop it is better to make it a local variable of the loop.

So I would rewrite the program the following way

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int N = 5;
   int theSum = 0;

   for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) theSum += i + 1;

   cout << "The sum of first " << N << " natural numbers is " << theSum << endl;    

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's called an "unspecified value" and, worse, it's UB to read from it (which is required by the `+=`). It's better to think of the uninitialised object as not having any value at all.

Comment: I though you will say something new...

Comment: Seems like this is new knowledge for you :)

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Thanks you are very helpful.

Comment: I am happy to help. Speaking of which, your code is invalid because you wrote `'` instead of `"`.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit I updated the typo.